# How can I replace this clear plastic rectangle from inside of my DSLR piece?

Tags: repair, cleaning, diy, viewfinder, focusing-screen

While cleaning my camera, this piece was scratched.
What is its name? and is it possible to replace it?

[image: scratched]

Comment: How on Earth did you scratch that? That is well inside the camera body, if that is a focusing screen. Wasn't it just protecting the LCD? Because that is just a [LCD screen protective cover](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/For-nikon-D700-D800-D800E-Screen-protective-cover-for-D700-SLR-camera-LCD-screen-special-protective/1614590639.html) then.

Comment: That is much too small to be a rear LCD protective cover. It appears to be a focusing screen. Based on the relative size of the screen and the fingers holding it I would say it is probably from an APS-C camera (unless the person holding it has *very* large fingers.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a 'focusing screen'. You can easily obtain it either from the manufacturer directly, or from a camera store.

For example from [Adorama](http://www.adorama.com/searchsite/default.aspx?searchinfo=focusing%20screen)

Typically, for one model of camera there will be a few types of focusing screens that work with it. Your camera's manual will tell you which one has been installed by default, and which ones you can substitute for it.

Manufacturers can also are helpful: [Canon's guide to choosing a focusing screen](http://www.learn.usa.canon.com/app/pdfs/quickguides/CDLC_FocusingScreens_QuickGuide.pdf)

The only problem is that for a piece of plastic that they are, focusing screens are pretty pricey.

Also see the following questions: [What is a focusing screen](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23862/what-is-a-focusing-screen) and [How often to change it.](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13466/how-often-can-i-change-the-focusing-screen)

Comment: +1, although note that having a few types available is generally something that you'll see at the higher and sometimes middle of the lineup -- entry level cameras won't necessarily have options, and the manual might not mention the screen at all.

Comment: How easily and from whom you can obtain a replacement depends on the camera model. Canon, for example, considers the focusing screen for the 7D and 1D X not a user serviceable part and there are no official Canon replacement focusing screens available for those cameras.